# Which modifies which?

Tags: modifiers

> Kaldren returned to his seat and lay back quietly, his eyes gazing across the lines of exhibits. Half-asleep, periodically he leaned up and **adjusted the flow of light through the shutter**, thinking to himself, as he would do through the coming months, of Powers and his strange mandala, and of the seven and their journey to the white gardens of the moon, and the blue people who had come from Orion and spoken in poetry to them of ancient beautiful **worlds** beneath golden suns in the **island galaxies**, vanished for ever now in the myriad deaths of the cosmos.
>
> Ballard, J. G. The Complete Stories of J. G. Ballard

Does "through the shutter" modify "the flow of light"? I ask because I didn't find "adjust something + adverb/preposition" collocation in the dictionary. Thus, I don't think it's an object complement.

What does **island galaxies** mean? "vanished" modify **island galaxies** or **worlds**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes: Kaldren adjusted how much light flowed through the shutter. (Presumably what  he actually manipulated was the shutter; but his object was to adjust the amount and quality of light which the shutter admitted.)
2. "Island galaxies" are galaxies *isolated* by immense distances from other entitities in the universe, galaxies which are not associated with other galaxies in groups, clusters and superclusters.
3. The participle clause headed by *vanished* probably modifies the *ancient beautiful worlds*, since syntactically the suns and galaxies occur in subordinate participle phrases and semantically it is the worlds which are the subject of the poetry and the blue people who spoke it.

Comment: 1. Can I just say "adjusted the light" instead? 2. here "vanished"="which vanished"?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng 'Adjusted the light' suggests adjusting the fixture which provided the light. The sense of an adjectival pa.ppl. of a transitive verb is perfective:  it "**had** vanished". You may *paraphrase* this with a relative clause, *which had vanished*. Some grammarians treat the participle phrase as a 'reduced' relative clause, but I think this is a reach.

Comment: I see. Just like "fallen leaves". "The myriad deaths of the cosmos" sounds a literary style. Does it mean numerous repetitive deaths of the universe?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Technically, a *myriad* is ten thousand, but practically nobody knows that. In ordinary use it's just a poetically vast number.